# Обьясните поведение рекурсии

Tags: рекурсия, javascript

Не могу понять почему функция с рекурсией выдает разные значения

```
function pow(x) {
if (x==1)
return 1;
else
return x + pow(x-1);    
}
alert(pow(3));
```

Выдает число 6,(ожидаемый результат) , если заместо x поставить 3 т.е то значение которое передаю будет выдавать 7

```
function pow(x) {
if (x==1)
return 1;
else
return 3 + pow(x-1);    
}
alert(pow(3));
```

Поясните как работает рекурсия во втором примере и почему 7 а не 6 .

Comment: попробуйте выполнить функцию по шагам и сами увидите: 

1. x = 3; результат = 3 + pow(2)
2. x = 2 результат = 3 + pow(1) + 3 (предыдущий_результат)
3. ч = 1 результат = 1 +  3 + 3 = 7

Comment: отладчиком пользоваться умеем? ну хотя бы console.log или alert?

1. 3+2+1 = x1+x2+x3
2. 3+3+1 = 3+3+x3

x1=3 x2=2 x3=1

Comment: @eicto, чем это лучше?

Comment: @dzhioev, тем что не блокируется интерфейс странички.

Comment: Так почему если изначально x=3 в первом примере и во 2ом просто подставить 3ку рекурсия будет возвращать опять 3ку

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5Dq6F/
возвращает с конца:

1,3+1=4,3+4=7

всё потому-что первым делом вычисляется 1, а потом 3+1, а потом 3+4

cделайте return 0 в условии и будет 6

Comment: @azazel7 вроде бы уже все по шагам объяснили, причем дважды. Почему бы вам  не воспользоваться отладчиком и не убедиться самому? Или религия не позволяет использовать отладчик?

Comment: @eicto сейчас вычисления модно в воркеры пихать.

Comment: @lampa это конечно, но вообще считать ресурсоемкую  алгебру на js - дурацкая затея сама по себе :) Но тут пример без хвостовой рекурсии, а это значит что память на больших итерациях просто сожрется.

Comment: @eicto как в этом случае происходят рекурсивные возвраты
http://jsfiddle.net/3cxMt/

Почему меняется порядок возврата?

Comment: @eicto меняется сейчас посмотрите ,закоментировал 2ой пример http://jsfiddle.net/3cxMt/4/
В 1) @@#
  2) #@@

Comment: а чего непонятного ? вы  пристраиваете в одном случае вывод к концу, а во втором к  началу... http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/3cxMt/6/

Comment: @eicto не могу понять как это схематично получается ,можете на примере обьяснить  поэтапно .

Answer (score 2):

До сих пор не понятна рекурсия? Смотрите, допустим функция pow у вас берет из корзины с бесконечным числом яблок столько этих фруктов, сколько указано в x и отдает вам. Изначально х = 3. Она возьмет 3 яблока, но, прежде чем отдать вам, выполнется еще раз при х = х - 1. На этот раз она отдаст вам 2 яблока, но она не жадная и выполнится еще раз. Все потому, что она так создана, брать каждый раз на 1яблоко меньше, пока не возьмет ровно 1 яблоко за раз. И вот, в последний раз она возьмес это яблоко. И отдаст все все вам. Сколько? 1 + 2 + 3 = 6 яблок. Но если бы она отдавала вам всегда 3 яблока (кроме случая, когда х = 1), хоть и принимала х = 3, потом х = 2 и т.д., то отдала бы 7 яблок: в первый раз 3 при х = 3, второй раз 3 при х = 2, в третий раз 1 при х = 1. Почему не 3? Потому что при х = 1 она возвращает не х + pow(x-1), а 1.

Comment: @psix-dev с самой рекурсией понятно, не понимаю на этом примере 2-ом http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/3cxMt/6/  как происходят рекурсивные возвраты.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/3cxMt/8/

Comment: @eicto, сбасибо надеюсь понял!
Посмотрите привилильно изобразил вызовы в комментарии.
http://jsfiddle.net/3cxMt/10/

Comment: @azazel7, да всё правильно, переходите на следующий уровень, вы познали рекурсию.